# Ordering of $\mathbb{Z_n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

How can one show that there is no ordering on $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

At first the answer seemed trivial to me as there is no inclusion of the sets, meaning they are all pairwise disjoint elements. Hence Ordering Cannot exists. However we are asked to specifically show the following properties do **not** hold

**i.)** if $a<b$ and $b<c$ then $a<c$

**ii.)** if $a<b$ then $a+c<b+c$

How would one show these specifically do not hold since there is no ordering I can come up with at all? Or is it enough to say that there is no ordering without proving these specific examples?

Comment: There are loads of orderings. For instance, the ordering inherited from $\Bbb Z$ works on $\{0,1,2,\ldots, n\}$, and thus $\Bbb Z_n$, and satisfies i.) However, it fails to satisfy ii.) because $0<n$ but $0+1\not<n+1=0$. You have to show that this happens no matter what you try.

Comment: Doesn't $\mathbb{z}_n$ traditionally denote all the equivalence relation sets in mod n. Meaning like it partitions $\mathbb{z}$.I understand your answer if we are simply dealing with numbers, but we are dealing with sets here. Unless I'm misunderstanding mathematical notation or we can use similar reasoning for sets

Comment: If you have an ordering of $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, then that is easily translated into an order on the corresponding equivalence classes in $\Bbb Z_n$.

Comment: At some point one tires of writing $[k]$ or $\bar k$ to denote the congruence class of $k$, and start just writing $k$. And one doesn't lose much in the process.

Comment: I very much appreciate your help. In order to show that “this happens no matter what you try” from your first comment, I assume you mean show despite what ordering you put the equivalence classes in. Can one state that they are disjoint from one another, so a totally ordered set can’t be defined. Or how would u go about “showing that this happens no matter what you try”.

Comment: "they are disjoint from one another, so a totally ordered set can’t be defined" What? Why would that affect anything? Sure, you can't let $\subseteq$ be the order relation, but you can order $\Bbb Z$ even though the numbers themselves are disjoint. Declaring one thing to be larger than some other thing in a new order you are inventing from scratch has nothing to do with whether the two are in any way previously related. And you can invent $n!$ different total orders on $\Bbb Z_n$ (that fulfill i.)) However, none of them fulfill ii.), and that is what you are asked to prove.

Comment: I see, we can just define the ordering relation any way we so choose (any order) “<“. I originally thought the ordering of these sets could only be defined by the inclusion argument I was falsely using. I truly thank you for your time as I am now much more confident in understanding the problem at hand

Answer (score 4):

Of course you need to prove it rigorously. If there is a total order $<$ over $\mathbb Z_n$, then either $1>0$ or $1<0$. What happens if you add the inequality to itself $n$ times?

Edit: note that the proof uses the fact that if $a<b$ and $c<d$ then $a+c<b+d$. This is because $a+c<b+c$ (by property $\mathrm{ii}$), and $b+c<b+d$ (again by property $\mathrm{ii}$). Then by property $\mathrm{i}$, we get $a+c<b+c$ and $b+c<b+d$ implies $a+c<b+d$.

Comment: Once again, we are dealing with sets here, not numbers. Perhaps your argument for Z modulo n is the same as for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ which I thought was traditionally defined to be the equivalence classes for all  $0$$\leq$i$\leq$$(n-1)$. Hence it partitions $\mathbb{Z}$. For some reason this ordering of sets is confusing me, would u convert to $\mathbb{Z}$ modulo then apply ur above reasoning?

Comment: The fact that adding an inequality to itself (or really just adding two inequalities) preserves the inequality direction is not a given property. So that will need to be proven in some way. In this case I think it's just as easy to go for a direct proof.

Comment: @Rick We identify the set $\{a,a+n,a-n,a+2n,a-2n,\dots\}$ with the number $a$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,

> If $G$ is a finite group, then the unique partial order on $G$
>   compatible with the product is the equality.

**Proof**. Suppose that $a \leqslant b$ for some $a, b \in G$. Setting $c = ba^{-1}$, one gets $1 = aa^{-1} \leqslant ba^{-1} = c$. It follows that, for every $n > 0$, $c^n \leqslant c^{n+1}$. Thus
$$
  1 \leqslant c \leqslant c^2 \leqslant \dotsm \leqslant c^{|G|} = 1
$$
whence $c = 1$ and $a = b$.

Comment: @Arthur The order you propose is called *equality*, so this is exactly the result I wrote (which does not require a total order).

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question thanks to the help of all of you, I have come up with the following reasoning:

If you define any total ordering on the set $\mathbb{Z}_n$, there must exist a unique maximal element. Since two elements in the set produce this maximal element, say $a+b=m$. One can say that though $a<m$ this does not imply $a+b<m+b$ since we defined $a+b=m$ and $m$ is the maximal element hence $m+b$ cannot be “greater” than it so to say.

Comment: Please share feedback if my counterexample proof above is correct mathematical reasoning or flawed

Comment: As long as you specify that $b\neq 0$ (or equivalently that $a\neq m$), this seems fine to me.